# How to unit test react final form's Field Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-final-form, final-form

I am writing a form component using react-final-form library. As component starts growing, I split it into multiple sub components such that parent component has the `<Form>{... }</Form>` component and related `<Field>{... }</Field>` are in separate components. Now, I'm trying to write unit test for my separated sub components containing `<Field></Field>`, I'm getting the error as `<Field>{... }</Field>` have dependency on `<Form>{... }</Form>` and cannot run separately. Below is the exact error message which shows up when I try to run unit test.

> useField must be used inside of a  component

One way I can solve this is to mock my actual `<Field>{... }</Field>` component in its unit test, but I feel that won't be a correct approach as for unit test I'm mocking the actual component which needs to get tested.

Could someone please help me what way should I go for ? Is it the right way to mock the component in its own unit test and then test it or should I have to think of restructuring my parent `<Form>` and its sub components ? And how can I restructure it better, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Field` component uses [useField](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/v6.5.9/src/Field.js#L32) hook, `useField` hook uses [useForm](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/v6.5.9/src/useField.js#L54) underly. `useForm` uses [React.useContext(ReactFinalFormContext)](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/v6.5.9/src/useForm.js#L9) underly. As you can see, it uses `ReactFinalFormContext`, so the component which uses this react context must be a descendant of [ReactFinalFormContext.Provider](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/v6.5.9/src/ReactFinalForm.js#L196). `ReactFinalFormContext.Provider` is provided by `Form` component.

I recommend you to use [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) to test your react components.

It's not recommended to mock the component, you should test your components

> in the way a user would use them. Users don't care what happens behind the scenes, they just see and interact with the output.

For more, see [Why should I use React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/migrate-from-enzyme#why-should-i-use-react-testing-library)

You should wrap your `Field` custom component with a `Form` component. See [official test recipes](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/v6.5.9/src/Field.test.js#L64)

E.g.

```
  it("should render via children render function", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmitMock}>
        {() => (
          <form>
            <Field name="name">
              {({ input }) => <input {...input} data-testid="name" />}
            </Field>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>,
    );
    expect(getByTestId("name")).toBeDefined();
  })
```

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2, links you shared were really helpful.